# MySQL error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, mysql-error-1241

I am trying to Insert data from a table1 into table2

```
insert into table2(Name,Subject,student_id,result)
select (Name,Subject,student_id,result)
from table1;
```

Key for table2 is student_id.

Assume that there are not any duplicates.

I get the error: `MySQL error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

There are only four columns in table2.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Syntax error, remove the `( )` from `select`.

```
insert into table2 (name, subject, student_id, result)
select name, subject, student_id, result
from table1;
```

Comment: This solved my problem too.  But I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 27):

Just remove the `(` and the `)` on your SELECT statement:

```
insert into table2 (Name, Subject, student_id, result)
select Name, Subject, student_id, result
from table1;
```

Comment: OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
[SQL: INSERT INTO meedan_newsartcile_details (identifier, `@context`, `@type`, `datePublished`, url, author, `claimReviewed`, `text`, image, `reviewRating`, verdict, I am getting error, how to solve? article_title, type, `ratingValue`, `bestRating`, author_name, author_url, `ID`, news_source) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)]

Comment: @SUSHMAKUMARI I think you've put variable names in the insertion field list spec: ```@context``` and ```@type``` are not field names are they?  Rather they are data you wish to write into whatever those fields are actually called

Answer (score 9):

Another way to make the parser raise the same exception is the following incorrect clause.

```
SELECT r.name
FROM roles r
WHERE id IN ( SELECT role_id ,
                     system_user_id
                 FROM role_members m
                 WHERE r.id = m.role_id
                 AND m.system_user_id = intIdSystemUser
             )
```

The nested `SELECT` statement in the `IN` clause returns two columns, which the parser sees as operands, which is technically correct, since the id column matches values from but one column (role_id) in the result returned by the nested select statement, which is expected to return a list.

For sake of completeness, the correct syntax is as follows.

```
SELECT r.name
FROM roles r
WHERE id IN ( SELECT role_id
                 FROM role_members m
                 WHERE r.id = m.role_id
                 AND m.system_user_id = intIdSystemUser
             )
```

The stored procedure of which this query is a portion not only parsed, but returned the expected result.