# Cannot make it to build this query

Tags: mysql

I just want to get the rows depending on where is the join. It is either `HOSPEDAJE` joining `HOTEL`, or `HOSPEDAJE` joining `APARTAMENTO`, but never at the same time.

I'm getting this error: `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Nombre,Ciudad,Provincia,Estrellas,Tipo,null,null) 
FROM hospedaje, hotel, habitacion
WHERE 
  hotel.hospedaje_id = hospedaje.id
  AND habitacion_id = habitacion.id

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT(Nombre,Ciudad,Provincia,null,null,Disponibles,Capacidad) 
FROM hospedaje, apartamento
WHERE apartamento.hospedaje_id = hospedaje.id
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820288/mysql-error-1241-operand-should-contain-1-columns)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT Nombre,Ciudad,Provincia,null as Estrellas,null as Tipo,Disponibles,Capacidad
FROM hospedaje, apartamento
WHERE apartamento.hospedaje_id = hospedaje.id

UNION

SELECT Nombre,Ciudad,Provincia,Estrellas,Tipo,null,null
FROM hospedaje, hotel, habitacion
WHERE 
  hotel.hospedaje_id = hospedaje.id
  AND habitacion_id = habitacion.id

ORDER BY 1
```

Union does a distinct anyway, you use union all otherwise.

the correct way to use distinct is without the (), for example

```
SELECT DISTINCT Nombre,Ciudad,Provincia,Estrellas,Tipo,null,null
FROM hospedaje, hotel, habitacion
WHERE 
  hotel.hospedaje_id = hospedaje.id
  AND habitacion_id = habitacion.id
```

Comment: Just another question... how can I sort all the results by Nombre? thanks so much