# insert if row count is 0

Tags: sql, mysql, conditional-statements, insert, mysql-error-1241

The following query works in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`address_tab1`
(`city`,`street_name`,`pincode`)

SELECT
'mycity1', 'mystreerName1', '4855881'

where (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`.`address_tab1`) = 0;
```

But the following query does not work, although there are no syntax error.  Why so?  I would like to insert multiple rows.

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`address_tab1`
(`city`,`street_name`,`pincode`)

SELECT
('mycity1', 'mystreerName1', '4855881')

where (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`.`address_tab1`) = 0;
```

I get the following error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a list of expressions with parentheses, this is a *tuple*.  But each item in a select-list must be a scalar expression; they can't be tuples.

Another way of thinking of this is that when using `INSERT ... SELECT`, you're inserting the results of the `SELECT` into some columns. They are matched up by position.

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`address_tab1` 
    (`city`,   `street_name`,   `pincode`)
     ^1        ^2               ^3
SELECT 
    'mycity1', 'mystreerName1', '4855881'
    ^1         ^2               ^3
where (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`.`address_tab1`) = 0;
```

But if you tried to use a tuple in the select-list (even if it were supported, which it isn't) it would count as only one thing, so it would try to insert it into the first column of your `address_tab1` table. But inserting a tuple into a single column is not legal, and it would also leave no values for the other two columns in the insert-list.

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`address_tab1` 
    (`city`,                                `street_name`, `pincode`)
     ^1                                     ^2?            ^3?
SELECT 
    ('mycity1', 'mystreerName1', '4855881')
    ^1                                      ^2?            ^3?
where (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`.`address_tab1`) = 0;
```

I'm using these markers like `^1` only to indicate each column in these examples. These markers are not part of SQL syntax.

---

Re your comment:

> I can use the above method to create separate queries for each record that I want to add to the table. Is there a way I can do it in one query.

I would use a new syntax of MySQL 8.0: the [VALUES statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html). This allows you to specify multiple rows of literal values.

```
INSERT INTO test.address_tab1 
SELECT * FROM (
  VALUES 
   ROW('mycity1', 'mystreetName1', '4855881'),
   ROW('mycity2', 'mystreetName2', '1885584'),
   ...
) AS t
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`.`address_tab1`) = 0;
```

If you are not using MySQL 8.0 yet, you should upgrade, because support for MySQL 5.x is ending soon.

Comment: I know there is an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820288/mysql-error-1241-operand-should-contain-1-columns) that says you must remove the parentheses and not use a tuple, but it doesn't explain why this is required. I found other questions about MySQL error 1241, but none explained the reason.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  I would like to add multiple records into a table if there are no records in the table.  I can use the above method to create separate queries for each record that I want to add to the table.   Is there a way I can do it in one query.? Hope you have understood my question.

Comment: INSERT INTO address_tab1 
VALUES 
 ROW('mycity1', 'mystreetName1', '4855881'),
 ROW('mycity2', 'mystreetName2', '1885584'),
 ...;
When I tried to add where or if clause to check if there are no records in table, I get error - "where is not valid in this position"
By the by, I am using MySQL 8.0.31.  Thanks

Comment: Okay, I've edited to show how to use it with a WHERE clause.